# How to define an interface with properties?

Tags: go

I have a question: is it possible to set an interface for a linear space?

Let me remind you that in linear space L there is an operation of adding elements and multiplying an element by a number. Moreover, two properties are fulfilled:

1)*a+b in L*

2)*ak in L*, where *k* - scalar

I presented the interface for linear space in the following form:

```
type Point interface {
}

type LinSpace interface {
    Sum(x, y Point)
    Prod(x Point, k float64)
}
```

how can i account for the above two properties in the interface definition?

Comment: Can you show an example of how you'd like to use the interface?

Comment: I used this as a fictional example of an interface, there is no real use. It became interesting to me whether it is possible to somehow impose properties on the interface, and not just definitions of methods.

Comment: https://appliedgo.com/blog/generic-interface-functions looks promising

Comment: It doesn't seem like you mentioned any properties (except for that those two methods should exist, which is the normal use of interfaces). Do you mean there is some kind of specific mathematical relationship the interface should satisfy? If so, you can't enforce that with the Go type system.

Comment: Interfaces can't have fields. They can only have methods. If you must, add getters and setters. Or use a struct type instead of an interface type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interfaces can contain only methods.

You can do something like this:

```
    // Effective Go says: interface names should contain prefix -er 
    type LinSpacer interface {
        Sum() float64
        Prod(k float64) float64
    }
    
    // Struct that implements interface
    type LinSpaceImpl struct {
        A float64
        B float64
    }
    
    // Implementation of Sum() method
    // Also, You don't need to pass A and B vars
    // because they're already exist in LinSpaceImpl
    func (l *LinSpaceImpl) Sum() float64 {
        return l.A + l.B
    }
    
    // Implementation of Prod() method
    // Unlike the Sum() method, here we need extra param - k
    // So it has to be passed, or You can add it to
    // LinSpaceImpl as another fields but it doesn't
    // make any sense though
    func (l *LinSpaceImpl) Prod(k float64) float64 {
        return l.A * k
    }
    
    // Unnecessary "constructor" to optimize Your main function
    // And clarify code
    func NewLinSpace(a, b float64) LinSpacer {
    // Since LinSpaceImpl correctly implements LinSpacer interface
    // You can return instance of LinSpaceImpl as LinSpacer
        return &LinSpaceImpl{
            A: a,
            B: b,
        }
    }
```

And then you can do this in your main (or other) function:

```
    // Use any float values
    ls := NewLinSpace(11.2, 24.7)
    
    fmt.Println(ls.Sum())      // 35.9
    fmt.Println(ls.Prod(30.2)) // 338.23999999999995
```

This is how "OOP" works in Go.